# За что ставят минусы на авторский ответ?

Tags: обсуждение, голоса-против, самоответы, голоса-на-ответах

За что ставят минусы на авторский ответ?

Я задал вопрос [Есть ли в Windows аналог /dev/null?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1511842).

В комментариях мне сказали решение, я оформил это как ответ самому себе.

Дня два всё было хорошо, но на второй-третий день кто-то поставил "минус" на мой ответ.

Вообще можно ли отвечать самому себе так?

> Ответ уже нашелся:
>
> ```sh
> cmd > nul
> ```
>
> Спасибо @PavelGridin.

Если нет, то объясните почему.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ответы самому себе писать — абсолютно нормальная практика. Минус, видимо, поставили из-за полноты ответа. Мне, например, было бы приятно в ответе видеть почему nul, какую-нибудь ссылку на документацию и т.п.

Если же расписывать нечего или лень, лучше оставить ответ как есть в комментариях.

Comment: Как вариант перевести то что [здесь написано](https://ss64.com/nt/nul.html)

Comment: Я серьёзно поправил свой ответ, и вставил эту ссылку.

Comment: @nchistov это не документация, а блог. Объяснение там хорошее, можно его перевести или же перевести что-то с английского SO. В общем, чтобы как база знаний выглядело. (минус не я поставил если что)

Comment: @nchistov рекомендую вам почитать сложившуюся дискуссию под вопросом и оформить это в ответ, нюансов то много

Comment: @DiMithras мне кажется нет смысла дискуссию куда-то оформлять, там больше придирки к терминам (на мой взгляд). Того что в ответе есть вполне достаточно.

Comment: "из-за полноты ответа" - наоборот, из-за **не**полноты.

Comment: @Зонтик имелось ввиду такое свойство как "полнота" ;)

Answer (score 6):

Те, кто ставят минусы **не думая** это треш и пренебрежение. Это не вам минус, а они себе ставят (*в случае, если не справедливо, ведь зрячие пока еще остались, и если минусуют из вредности то это видно*) и еще если не объясняют почему‍♀️, но бывает например **ответ** автора и правда **лишь бы дать ответ**, и тогда например я приведу личный [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1033804/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82), я сегодня поставила минус, сделала, чтобы привлечь внимание автора, и узнать более развернутый ответ. Кстати, я за минус тоже минус получила, но он зайдет, дополнит ответ... и я лично, уберу свой минус. А что касается, тех, кто просто тыкает на минусы, жаль, что невозможно это пресекать, ведь когда я например поставила минус, выходит **popUp**, где культурно написано **поясните пожалуйста…**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Порой когда мы задаем вопросы, в всплывающем окне выходят **схожие вопросы**. Я лично иду по всем ссылкам и читаю, чтоб пополнить базу знаний из практики пользователей, и чтоб не было дубликата в моем вопросе. И вот видя ответ короткий и совсем не ясный, как то коряво и хочется поправить, чтоб на этом сайте, все было полно и информативно, даже если это капелька.

*что касается вашего ответа, вам те, кто минус поставили, за ваше усердие, смею заметить плюсы на ответ сделали.*  И впредь ваши ответы будут всегда ясны для читающих.

Пока есть такие программисты, опытные, и которые хотят, чтоб и другие развивались, которые обоснованно ставят минусы, и тем самым **заставляют** становится лучше новичков. Это хорошо и это должно приветствоваться. Дай им Бог здоровья!!!

Comment: вроде по делу написано, здесь чего минусов накидывают? )) Хотя на мой взгляд кидать сразу минус, чтобы обратить внимание, тоже не очень. Оставить комментарий, и если игнорирует вот пару дней, то можно и минус поставить или за удаление проголосовать (требует достаточно репутации сие действо)

Comment: @Dmitry там был комментарий датой 2019 года и даже кто то стрелку вверх тыкнул, типа "согласен", понятное дело не совсем ясный, но реакции автора не было вот уже 4 года //```вроде``` еще не значит, что имеет право *"сказать что то)"*(надо пресечь сразу,,,,) )) вот и ```накидывают```

Comment: значит надо просто удалить этот ответ-комментарий и написать нормальный ответ, дайте ссылку на ответ

Comment: Не буду ставить минус, но попробую обратить на себя внимание

Comment: @DiMithras где и зачем =)? Вы и так в неплохо обратили на себя внимание выдвижением себя на выборах)

Comment: @Dmitry ха, спасибо! Да не за чем‥ я понимаю, что это не пикабу, но поюморить иногда хочется.

Comment: Btw, "*Пока есть такие программисты, опытные, и которые хотят, чтоб и другие развивались, которые обоснованно ставят минусы*", помню когда школьником был, словил пачку минусов на Siemens mobile, форум где прокачивали телефоны вроде Siemens S35, действительно мотивирует развиваться, именно тогда программированием увлёкся )

Answer (score 2):

Просто потому что людям хочется ставить минусы не думая. А фразы в духе "спасибо" и "ответ нашёлся" притягивают минусы как магнит. Да и короткие ответы - тоже.

Comment: *"А фразы в духе "спасибо" и "ответ нашёлся" притягивают минусы как магнит"* - сами по себе не притягивают, а только вкупе с куцым / низкокачественным ответом.

Comment: @Kromster прямо как этот :)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ ну не сказал бы. Хотя да, иронично, что участник со 120к репутации дал короткий плохой ответ получивший минусов и без "спасибо" и без "ответ нашелся" (кои все же характерны для самоответов).

Comment: @Kromster так "спасибо" и "ответ нашёлся" как раз есть в этом сообщении.

Comment: Вот ещё один с минусами. Правда не авторский.

Comment: @Зонтик, а у меня часто примерно поровну плюсов и минусов на мете)

Answer (score 1):

На авторский ответ редко ставлю минус, разве что если автор съязвил выкинуть свой ответ, который невозможно понять, и который зачастую низкого качества, или который отвергает другие ответы, потому что они ему не помогли.

Comment: Не очень понятно, что значит "отвергает другие ответы" и почему надо лепить минус автору, если другие ответы ему не подошли?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Бывает так, что автор написав вопрос получает несколько *хороших* ответов, и почему-то не один ответ его не удовлетворяет, и тогда он пишет свой *плохой* ответ и даже может поставить галочку на него.

Comment: Довольно необычный кейс, если ТС так себя ведёт, и "хорошие" ответы действительно решают его проблему лучше, чем его собственный "плохой" ответ. А есть ли на примете подобные ситуации, чтобы посмотреть на них лично?

Comment: Если так, если сяк - такое не подходит. Примеров куча, я не могу остановиться на каком либо из них, но это и не нужно. Голосование - анонимное, поэтому, мне нечего больше сказать.